# Could I get a count of how many leaves there are connecting each node at each level in Neo4j graph with Cypher?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

It would be helpful if I could get a count of how many leaves there are connecting each node at each level, and save that number as a label.

**As an example:**

(:Node:Root)->[:ACCESS]->(:Node:a)->[:ACCESS]->(:Node:c)

(:Node:Root)->[:ACCESS]->(:Node:a)->[:ACCESS]->(:Node:e)

(:Node:Root)->[:ACCESS]->(:Node:b)->[:ACCESS]->(:Node:d)

The root node has two nodes connected a,b

a has two nodes connected c,e

b has one node connected d

**What I would like to receive is:**

The root has 3 leaves connected

Node a has 2 leaves connected

Node b has 1 leaf connected

Node c,d, and e have 0 leaves connected

******* This example has only two levels, but I need it to support an unknown number of levels

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the nodes and their leaves count as follows

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:ACCESS*]->(leaf) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS((leaf)-[:ACCESS]->())

RETURN n, COUNT(DISTINCT leaf) AS leaves
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, Graphileon! It's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!